Navegador guarda caché viejo de sitio web
Quería comentarles un problema que tengo hace tiempo y todavía no le encuentro la solución.
Alojo todos los sitios webs de mis clientes en Hostinger. Anda todo bien, pero al momento de hacer algún cambio en los archivos, o eliminarlos para subir archivos nuevos los cambios no se actualizan porque hostinger o el navegador guarda el caché de la web.
Al momento de hacer algún cambio, mi cliente no lo puede ver debido a este tema y tengo que indicarle como borrar caché para que pueda ver los cambios.
Si entro desde otro navegador donde no he entrado al sitio aún, la web se ve actualizada así que supongo que es el navegador que mantiene los datos viejos del sitio.
Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto y que el caché se borre automáticamente cuando hago cambios o remplazo archivos?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! depende quien mantenga el cache.. igual ctrl+f5 fuerza recargar la pagina sin necesidad de borrar nada... de paso, fijate si no es tume del hosting... muchos tienen cache para hacerte ahorrar...

Yo recargo la página pulsando el botón de refresco del navegador que aparece en la barra superior, a la vez que mantengo pulsada la tecla "Shift" (desplazamiento) pues eso teoricamente refresca la cache del navegador (al menos en firefox acostumbra a funcionar).  Y en caso de que no me funcione inspecciono la página (F12) y borro las cookies y todo lo que haya almacenado en el storage.  O con Shift+Control+R (mantenlo pulsado en ese orden)

[CTRL] + [F5] recarga todos los componentes de la página de cero.

El caché puede estar guardado desde distintos puntos (Cloudfare, Wordpress, Cache Manager, etc), debes saber cuál es, para limpiarlo donde corresponda, sin tener que indicarle al cliente que haga eso cada vez que cambias algo. Revisa este post y además este otro los cuales explican lo relativo al caché en el caso de Hostinger. Según tu caso, procede como corresponda.

Por otra parte, si la web en cuestión está basada en algún Framework, tales como Symfony, Laravel, CodeIgniter, CakePHP, etc... los mismos tienen su forma propia de manejar el caché y por lo general lo puedes limpiar con una simple instrucción desde la línea de comandos del servidor en cuestión, o subiendo nuevas versiones de los archivos que quieres cambiar.

Hola Emiliano, una forma es agregar un parámetro en la URL al recurso para indicar la versión, por ejemplo, /estilos.css?v=1.0.2. Otra forma más automática es agregar el encabezado ETag
